# Deregistered student resident permit. Can I go buy something and apply for VAT refund when I leave Germany?

Tags: germany, tax-refunds

I came to Germany from the USA for my master's program. I have finished my degree and am planning on leaving Germany soon. I have deregistered my resident status and would like to know if I go buy something before leaving, would I be able to get tax refund since I am no longer a resident here (and have a one-way ticket back home).

Thanks in advance for any information.

Answer (score 1):

> ... if I go buy something before leaving, would I be able to get tax refund since I am no longer a resident here (and have a one-way ticket back home).

In theory yes, since you are no longer a resident and the product was bought after you deregistered.

You would have to show customs the product (in its original packaging) with reciept and the deregistration confirmation when leaving the *European Union Customs Area*.

It should be noted that such goods, depending on the jurisdiction, **may not be considered household goods** when returning to your home country (and thus are normally not taxed when importing).

For the *European Union Customs Area*, such goods must be owned **and used** by you for at least 6 months before departure.

---

> [COUNCIL REGULATION (EC) No 1186/2009 of 16 November 2009 setting up a Community system of reliefs from customs duty](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=celex%3A32009R1186#d1e282-23-1)
> **Article 4**
>
> The relief shall be limited to personal property which:
> (a) except in special cases justified by the circumstances, has been in the possession of and, in the case of non-consumable goods, **used by the person concerned** at his former normal place of residence **for a minimum of six months** before the date on which he ceases to have his normal place of residence in the third country of departure;
> ...

Comment: Thank you Mark for the info!!